# What are the differences between the app.vue and pages/index.vue files in Nuxt?

Tags: vuejs3, web-frontend, nuxtjs3

I'm new to Nuxt and got confused about when to use app.vue or /pages/index.vue .When do I use either of them or what is the purpose of using index.vue if the starting point is app.vue .

Answer (score 3, accepted):

`app.vue` is your main entry point, like `main.js` in Vue, the top level you can get access to if you want to have some thing across your whole app.

`/pages/index.vue` is used to generate some content on the home of your app aka `/`, this is mainly some vue-router path done for you.
In the same way, `/pages/about.vue` will generate a page for `/about`.

So, mainly all the router pages are contained within `app.vue`.